# Большое количество лямбд

Tags: java, kotlin

я пишу игру на kotlin, и для удобства, рассматриваю вариант реализации квестов в виде лямбд.

```
val quests = ArrayList<Quest>()
```

Допустим, у нас есть квест, после выполнения которого происходит определённое событие. Если я сделаю нечто вроде подобного:

```
quests.add(Quest({ лямбда когда квест был взят }, { лямбда когда квест был завершен }))
```

Какие проблемы могли бы возникнуть, теоретически, если бы таких квестов было ооооочень много? Как я понял, на каждую лямбду создаётся класс? Есть ли проблемы, связанные с переизбытком классов?

Comment: При таком подходе когда у вас будет десяток квестов, вы получите гигантскую простыню из кода, в которой практически невозможно будет ориентироваться. И если вы планируете делать содержимое кода в каждой из лямбда длиннее пары строк кода, то будет не просто нечитаемой простыней, но и еще она будет вызывать настоящую боль каждый раз когда надо будет сделать хоть минимальное изменения.
Переизбыток классов вы создать не сможете, ну только если вы не планируете запускать свою игру на калькуляторе с 10 килобайтами памяти.

Comment: переизбыток классов? а как вы думаете, во что превращаются лямбды после компиляции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, создание класса для лямбды в современном Kotlin происходит только при компиляции для JDK 1.6, при компиляции для JDK 1.8 и новее для лямбды создается лишь только функция, а экземпляр функционального типа создается с помощью инструкции `invokedynamic`, что избавляет от всех возможных проблем создания класса. Если вам все-таки нужно компилировать код для JDK 1.6, то единственная возможная проблема — это превышения лимита классов на некоторых платформах. Например, на Android в одном файле dex лимит в 65536 классов, который нужно [специальным образом обходить](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).